# How to loop through an array, randomly output two strings, and execute them against the answer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I have four groups, each group contains three keys: **question**, **hint**, and **answer**. I need to randomly output only two values of **question** and **hint**, then execute them against the **answer** value, where the user has to enter in a text field. My thought is to loop through the entire array, then randomly output, and finally do the execution.

How can this be possible? http://jsfiddle.net/vo01u94p/

**jQuery/JS**

```
$('.submit').on('click', function () {
    var HISTORY;
    var question_1 = {
        question: 'When did Martin Luther King, Jr. die?',
        hint: 'He was born on January 15, 1929 and he died at the age of 39.',
        answer: 'April 4, 1968',
    };
    var question_2 = {
        question: 'Who discovered America?',
        hint: 'This person led three ships - the Nina, the Pinta and the Santa Maria - out of the Spanish port of Palos on August 3, 1492.',
        answer: 'Christopher Columbus',
    };
    var question_3 = {
        question: 'What event occured on July 4, 1776?',
        hint: 'Thomas Jefferson played an important role.',
        answer: 'The United States Declaration of Independence was written',
    };
    var question_4 = {
        question: "What continent covers 8.3% of the Earth's total surface area (28.4% of its land area)?",
        hint: 'Also known as the New World',
        answer: 'The Americas, or America',
    };
    var questions = [];
    questions[0] = question_1;
    questions[1] = question_2;
    questions[2] = question_3;
    questions[3] = question_4;
    var library = {
        questions: questions
    }
    var libraries = [];
    libraries[HISTORY] = library;
    var questionNo = 3;
    console.log(libraries[HISTORY].questions[questionNo].question);
    console.log(libraries[HISTORY].questions[questionNo].hint);
    console.log(libraries[HISTORY].questions[questionNo].answer);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it like so :

Use a variable `r = Math.floor(Math.random()*(questions.length));` to get a random question in your list, then pick up the question, if the answer is incorrect, show the hint, and if the answer is correct, [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) that last question from your array.

```js
var question_1 = {
  question: 'When did Martin Luther King, Jr. die?',
  hint: 'He was born on January 15, 1929 and he died at the age of 39.',
  answer: 'April 4, 1968'
};
var question_2 = {
  question: 'Who discovered America?',
  hint: 'This person led three ships - the Nina, the Pinta and the Santa Maria - out of the Spanish port of Palos on August 3, 1492.',
  answer: 'Christopher Columbus'
};
var question_3 = {
  question: 'What event occured on July 4, 1776?',
  hint: 'Thomas Jefferson played an important role.',
  answer: 'The United States Declaration of Independence was written'
};
var question_4 = {
  question: "What continent covers 8.3% of the Earth's total surface area (28.4% of its land area)?",
  hint: 'Also known as the New World',
  answer: 'The Americas, or America'
};


var questions = [];
questions[0] = question_1;
questions[1] = question_2;
questions[2] = question_3;
questions[3] = question_4;

function newQuestion() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (questions.length));
  $('#question').html(questions[r].question);
  $('button').unbind();
  $('button').click(function() {
    ($('#usr_answer').val() == questions[r].answer) ? goodAnswer(r): badAnswer(r);
  });
}

function goodAnswer(r) {
  $('#response').html('that was a god answer');
  $('#question').html('');
  $('#hint').html('');
  questions.splice(r, 1);
  (questions.length == 0) ? $('#response').html('No More questions'): newQuestion();
}

function badAnswer(r) {
  $('#hint').html(questions[r].hint);
  $('#response').html('Please try again');
}
$(newQuestion());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="question"></p>
<p id="hint"></p>
<p>
  <input type="text" id="usr_answer" />
</p>
<button type="button" style="padding: 4px 22px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">OK</button>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for at the beginning. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try this, use a for loop

see output below

```js
    $('.submit').click( function(){
  
  var HISTORY;
  
  var question_1 = {
     question: 'When did Martin Luther King, Jr. die?',
     hint: 'He was born on January 15, 1929 and he died at the age of 39.',
     answer:'April 4, 1968',
     };
  var question_2 = {
     question: 'Who discovered America?',
     hint: 'This person led three ships - the Nina, the Pinta and the Santa Maria - out of the Spanish port of Palos on August 3, 1492.',
     answer:'Christopher Columbus',
     };
  var question_3 = {
     question: 'What event occured on July 4, 1776?',
     hint: 'Thomas Jefferson played an important role.',
     answer:'The United States Declaration of Independence was written',
     };
  var question_4 = {
     question: "What continent covers 8.3% of the Earth's total surface area (28.4% of its land area)?",
     hint: 'Also known as the New World',
     answer:'The Americas, or America',
     };
     
  
  var questions = [];    
  questions[0] = question_1;
  questions[1] = question_2;
  questions[2] = question_3;
  questions[3] = question_4;
  
  
  var library = { questions : questions }
  var libraries = [];
  libraries[HISTORY] = library;
  var questionNo = 3;
 
        for(a=0;a<libraries[HISTORY].questions.length;a++){ $("body").append("<br/>"+libraries[HISTORY].questions[a].question+"<br/>");
                                                          }
    
  

  
  
  
  
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" /></p>
<button class='submit' type="button" style="padding: 4px 22px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">OK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). This will let you loop through an array and give you access to the index and the value. The `JQuery` documentation has a few examples that you can follow.

```
$.each(libraries, function(key, library) {
 $.each(library.questions, function(key, question) {
    console.log("Question: " + question.question);
    console.log("Hint: " + question.hint);
    console.log("Answer: " + question.answer);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a variable to generate a random value which is in decimal and set the range of the decimal value.

use a for loop with two iterations.
example: if the rand value comes in the range 0.0 to 0.25, ask question no. 1,

.26 to .50 ask question no 2 and so on

and once the first iteration is about to end, remove that question index from the array list and 
perform the 2nd iteration.

like this you could generate two questions randomly.

Comment: Yes, that's good for what I asked but the truth is that I have more than 200 questions.

Comment: Oh.
then @kaiido's answer is best suited